# CPU cooler for peltier cooling system

Tags: heat-sink, cooling

I am in the process of building a "chill chamber" for electronic experiments <sup>*</sup> and as primary part for cooling it I am going to use a peltier element. This means though I need to get rid of probably around 150W, and my first thought for that was to use an older CPU cooler which had heatpipes, but unfortunately the contact area of the ground plate was smaller than the peltier element. I then turned to look what is available on the market, and its overwhelmingly much, and besides specs often not being clear nowhere I could almost never find specifications of the size of the contact plate/area (or whatever you call it). So for this special application I search for a cooling system with the following needs:

- Contact area at least 40mm x 40mm
- Mounting ability for 120mm fan
- Fan must blow from the side
- Of course best price for performance, price should not really exceed ~40EUR
- Heatpipes
- If it has direct contact heatpipes, the typical gap between the heatpipes and the rest of the contact area metal may not be bigger than 0.2mm
- Size (without fans) should not exceed roughly 150mm cube

The following feature might be nice, but need not to be included:

- A fan (don't care about noise, can run at 4000rpm)
- Possibility for push/pull fan mounting
- direct heatpipe contact
- all contact area copper
- heatsinking fins copper

<sub><sup>*</sup>well of course also for beer.</sub>

Comment: If the CPU cooler doesn't have enough area for the peltier element you could use a heat spreader.

Comment: While TEC modules are pretty cool devices, they aren't all that effective when the [core is under load](http://www.legitreviews.com/the-chilltec-thermoelectric-cpu-cooler-review_491/5).

Comment: @BennettYeo: luckily this is for a chamber in which complete low power devices are placed and cooled down

Comment: most 12V Peltiers in of themselves produce upwards of 110W of heat.

Comment: @tuskiomi: there are many different ones, and you can not only chose the right one, but also drive them with lower current

Comment: If you don't drive them with enough current, they become insulators. In 99% of cases, you won't have peltier cooler Constant Current source. and in 90% of those cases , the 5V rail isn't enough to drive a cooler properly for a cpu under load- it'd fry it. that leaves 89% of cases to be hooked up to a 12V supply, maybe with a VDC switch. The whole time, you must be supplying enough power to not only move the heat off the CPU, but to move its own heat off as well. If this fails, you're insulating the CPU, causing temperatures to rise, and thus peltier resistance rises, and so the cooling lowers

Comment: @tuskiomi: peltiers (as most semiconductor devices) are current driven, thus you obviously driven them with a (adjustable) constant current source. Besides that, the majority of nominal 12V elements need to be driven with much more, often up to 15.4V to operate at their max current, to achieve a max dT. With their resistance equivalent being available between typ. .8Ohm to 10Ohm and nominal voltage between 1.4V and 24V one has a wide variety to chose from if necessary. Consulting the datasheet before buying for a certain application is a useful thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the [Cooler Master Hyper 212 EVO](https://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=coolermaster%20evo&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Acoolermaster%20evo). It has 4 direct contact heat pipes and is rated for 180W thermal dissipation. And goes for about £30. You can also buy some clips and convert it to push-pull rather than just push.

The dimensions are (H,W,L) 158.5mm x 120mm x 77mm (1 fan) or ~100mm (2 fans).

Comment: Actually, it ships with clips for a second fan.